# variogramas kriging

Tags: interpolation

In order to find the altitude of a surface, we use the following method.

My question is: **What is the name of this method?**

We have

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & .. & .. & a_{1,n}&1&x_{1}&y_{1}\\ 
.. & .. & .. & ..&1&x_{2}&y_{2}\\ 
.. & .. &..  &.. &1&..&..\\ 
a_{n,1} &..  &..  &a_{n,n}&1&..&..\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
x_{1}&x_{2}&..&..&..&0&0\\
y_{1}&y_{2}&..&..&..&0&0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$z=\begin{pmatrix}
z_{1}\\ 
..\\ 
..\\ 
z_{n}\\ 
0\\
..\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ Where $a_{i,j}$ is the distance between the point $i$ and the point $j$.
$(x_{i},y_{i},z_{i})$ are the coordinates of the point $i$.

We calculate $L=A^{-1}z$

After that, we build the matrix $B$:

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
b_{1,1} & .. & .. & b_{1,n}&1&x'_{1}&y'_{1}\\ 
.. & .. & .. & ..&1&x'_{2}&y'_{2}\\ 
.. & .. &..  &.. &1&..&..\\ 
b_{m,1} &..  &..  &b_{m,n}&1&..&..\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
x_{1}&x_{2}&..&..&..&0&0\\
y_{1}&y_{2}&..&..&..&0&0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $b_{i,j}$ is the distance between the point $i$ we want to calculate the altitude and the measuring point $j$.
$(x'_{i},y'_{i},z'_{i})$ are the coordinates of the point $i$ we want to calculate the altitude.

finally,our unknown $z'$ is given by : $z'=BL$
where:$$
z'=\begin{pmatrix}
z'_{1}\\ 
..\\ 
..\\ 
z'_{n}\\ 
..\\
..
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thank you.